# PHPExcel Gradient Fill Effect

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am seeking gradient fill effect similar to the attached image[image], tried something like this but it's not working, has anybody done something similar? If yes, then please do share your feedback.

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A:C')->applyFromArray(
                    array(
                        'fill' => array(
                            'type'       => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                            'rotation'   => 90,
                            'startcolor' => array(
                                'argb' => 'FF007DC3'
                            ),
                            'endcolor'   => array(
                                'argb' => 'FFFFFFFF'
                            )
                        )
                    )
            );
```

PS: I do not need solid color, need gradient effect. Thanks.

Comment: no error....displays text normally

Comment: What writer are you using?

Comment: When you save a file in PHPExcel, you have to use a writer, (e.g. Excel5, Excel2007, CSV, PDF, HTML)..... what writer are you using?

Comment: There is not an Excel2016 writer for PHPExcel..... Excel2016 is the version of MS Excel you are using..... how do you save the file after you've made your changes to the gradient fill in PHPExcel?

Comment: @MarkBaker So sorry about the confusion, it's Excel5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I changed the writer from Excel5 to Excel2007 and it worked. Would like to thank @MarkBaker for the direction.